# NGINX error occurred when trying to get status page

Tags: nginx

Below is the nginx.conf file for my setup

```
user nginx;                                                                       
worker_processes auto;                                                            
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;                                               
pid /run/nginx.pid;                                                               
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;                                          
events {                                                                          
    worker_connections 1024;                                                      
}                                                                                 
http {                                                                            
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '     
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '                 
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';               
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;                                  
    sendfile            on;                                                       
    tcp_nopush          on;                                                       
    tcp_nodelay         on;                                                       
    keepalive_timeout   65;                                                       
    types_hash_max_size 2048;                                                     
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;                                    
    default_type        application/octet-stream;                                 
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;                                             

        upstream 135.250.138.150 {
      server 135.250.138.74:8666;
      server 135.250.138.75:8666;
      keepalive 50;
#      check interval=3000 rise=2 fall=2 timeout=1000 type=http;
    }

server {
#    listen       80 default_server;
#    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 80;
#    server_name  www.server.com;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    location / {
         proxy_pass http://135.250.138.150;
         proxy_set_header Connection "";
         proxy_http_version  1.1;
    }
    location /status {
       proxy_pass http://135.250.138.150;
       check_status;

    }
}

server {
#Start
#Added After SSL certification created
     listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
     listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
     server_name  _;
     root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
     keepalive_timeout 100s;
     ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/tls.key;
     ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
     ssl_session_timeout  10m;
     include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
     location /auth {
      proxy_pass https://135.250.138.150;
      proxy_http_version  1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
     error_page 404 /404.html;
         location = /40x.html {
     }
     error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
         location = /50x.html {
     }

     location /status {
       proxy_pass http://135.250.138.150;
       check_status;
     }

 }
}
```

Here is the details of log about the error from the file `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

> 2018/01/04 13:30:28 [error] 471#471: *47 http upstream check module
>   can not find any check server, make sure you've added the check
>   servers, client: 10.143.80.228, server: _, request: "GET /status
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04 13:30:30 [error]
>   471#471: *48 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/status" failed (2: No such
>   file or directory), client: 10.143.80.228, server: localhost, request:
>   "GET /status HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04 13:30:31
>   [error] 471#471: *48 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed
>   (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.143.80.228, server:
>   localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host:
>   "135.250.138.150", referrer: "http://135.250.138.150/status"
>   2018/01/04 13:31:09 [error] 471#471: *48 open()
>   "/usr/share/nginx/html/check_status" failed (2: No such file or
>   directory), client: 10.143.80.228, server: localhost, request: "GET
>   /check_status HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04 13:31:18
>   [error] 471#471: *50 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/check_status"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.143.80.228, server:
>   _, request: "GET /check_status HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04 13:31:18 [error] 471#471: *50 open()
>   "/usr/share/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or
>   directory), client: 10.143.80.228, server: _, request: "GET
>   /check_status HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04 13:31:24
>   [error] 471#471: *50 http upstream check module can not find any check
>   server, make sure you've added the check servers, client:
>   10.143.80.228, server: _, request: "GET /status HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04 13:39:38 [error] 471#471: *52 http
>   upstream check module can not find any check server, make sure you've
>   added the check servers, client: 10.143.80.228, server: _, request:
>   "GET /status HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04 13:39:45
>   [error] 471#471: *54 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/check_status"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.143.80.228, server:
>   localhost, request: "GET /check_status HTTP/1.1", host:
>   "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04 13:39:50 [error] 471#471: *54 open()
>   "/usr/share/nginx/html/status" failed (2: No such file or directory),
>   client: 10.143.80.228, server: localhost, request: "GET /status
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04 13:39:57 [error]
>   471#471: *56 http upstream check module can not find any check server,
>   make sure you've added the check servers, client: 10.143.80.228,
>   server: _, request: "GET /status HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150"
>   2018/01/04 13:42:13 [error] 1355#1355: *2 http upstream check module
>   can not find any check server, make sure you've added the check
>   servers, client: 10.143.80.228, server: _, request: "GET /status
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04 13:42:20 [error]
>   1355#1355: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/status" failed (2: No such
>   file or directory), client: 10.143.80.228, server: localhost, request:
>   "GET /status HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04 13:43:19
>   [error] 1419#1419: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/status" failed (2:
>   No such file or directory), client: 10.143.80.228, server: localhost,
>   request: "GET /status HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04
>   13:43:26 [error] 1419#1419: *3 http upstream check module can not find
>   any check server, make sure you've added the check servers, client:
>   10.143.80.228, server: _, request: "GET /status HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04 13:43:27 [error] 1419#1419: *6 http
>   upstream check module can not find any check server, make sure you've
>   added the check servers, client: 10.143.80.228, server: _, request:
>   "GET /status HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04 13:46:30
>   [error] 1567#1567: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/status" failed (2:
>   No such file or directory), client: 10.143.80.228, server: localhost,
>   request: "GET /status HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150" 2018/01/04
>   13:46:40 [error] 1567#1567: *4 http upstream check module can not find
>   any check server, make sure you've added the check servers, client:
>   10.143.80.228, server: _, request: "GET /status HTTP/1.1", host: "135.250.138.150"